# OpenCV as a web service

Tags: c++, web-services, opencv, face-recognition

i am looking into facial recognitions using Local Binary Pattern Histogram have came across OpenCV. Within OpenCV, the Local Binary Pattern Histogram has a function which compares histograms "compareHist". How can i perform this function on a web server?. Is it possible to run OpenCV on a web server? (i am thinking about writing the whole function myself however it is based on multiple custom created classes and its rather troublesome - what language should i use? - this would be my last resort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV comes with [cv::FaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html), which includes Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces and **Local Binary Patterns Histograms**. It comes with a very detailed documentation, please see:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html

No need to implement it yourself. If you want to do this in another language, then you can easily look up the implementation in the contrib module of OpenCV. I am sure you can get some impression there.

As for the webserver. If you have a real server, then sure you could put OpenCV up there and interface with it. If you want to get something going real quick, have a look at the OpenCV Python bindings for cv::FaceRecognizer. I did a post on the OpenCV QA page just yesterday:

- http://answers.opencv.org/question/253/broken-python-bindings-with/?answer=255#post-id-255

However, it's a bit complicated due to an error on my side. There was a bug in the official OpenCV 2.4.2 release, so for the Python bindings to work you'll need the trunk version. Note, that the source code is now hosted with git, so you can get it with:

`git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git`

for example. Then if you are in Linux, you can follow this tutorial on how to install OpenCV:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

or if you are in Windows, then:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

might help. Make sure you have `python-dev` and `python-numpy` installed, so the Python bindings are compiled. If you are in Windows, simply install Python2.7 and NumPy (http://www.numpy.org).

You might be interested in my *Guide to Face Recognition with Python* also, which is available at:

- https://github.com/bytefish/facerecognition_guide

That shows a really lightweight implementation of two algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In regards to your second link, i am running python on Windows and i am unsure on how to run your scripts. I usually run the scripts using cmd (windows) however i seem to be getting errors and i do not know where i am going wrong (your guides say "python filename.py filepath). I have tried to research but have not been able to fix it. This is my error/attempt http://pastebin.com/6rMXHa3d . Are there other ways to run the script? maybe though the python idle? (i have installed opencv and python correctly, i can run normal opencv scripts e.g. filename.py)

Comment: Your pastebin snippets are OpenCV samples. I don't see, where these are *my scripts*. However, if you have problems working with OpenCV, you might have a better chance of getting help at: http://answers.opencv.org.

Comment: Hi Phillip, 

Sorry i have linked the wrong pastebin, it should be http://pastebin.com/bi91gVq4 . I am assuming that there should be a script 'createEigenFaceRecognizer' within python2 right - hence the error? but the git code does not have it there

Comment: Please build OpenCV from source. As I have written in the post: I have fixed the bindings only a week ago.

Comment: Hi Phillip, sorry if this is stupid to ask but as i said i am new to opencv. By building it from source do you mean to download the latest version of opencv and then run your script? would this fix the attribuite error?

Comment: Thank you, but still not sure where i am going wrong must of went thought it about 10 times so far. I have downloaded opencv from the trunk and went though the windows tutorial, installing all programs - including numpy but i am still receiving the same error. "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'". Where am i going wrong?. Other functions work fine in OpenCV

Comment: Weird, I'll check it as soon as possible.

Answer (score -4):

Disclaimer I am a founder.

Algorithmia provides OpenCV as a service through our API.

http://algorithmia.com/users/opencv